# Finding the length of an audio recording in iPhone

Tags: iphone, ipad, avaudiorecorder

I am recording the audio using avaudiorecorder. How do I find the length of the recording after saving the recording in a .caf file?

Comment: When u recording. u can put counter after every second.

Comment: is there any built in methods

Comment: And a few upvotes wouldn't hurt, either.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use helpers in the CoreMedia framework.

```
AVURLAsset *asset = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:avAudioRecorder.url options:nil];
CMTime time = asset.duration;
double durationInSeconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(time);
```

Comment: I tried this, but every time `durationInSeconds` is 0.00000. Do I need to need to import anything but `AVFoundation` and `CoreMedia`?